# Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $Z = X +Y$. Find $f_Z(z)$ if...

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables defined on the space $\Omega$, with density functions $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$, respectively. Suppose $Z = X + Y$. 
>   Find the density $f_Z(z)$ if $$f_X(x)=f_Y(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{x-3}2 &, & \text{if $3<x<5$,} \\
> 0 &, & \text{otherwise.}
> \end{cases}$$

Attempt: I tried to take the integral $$\int_{z}^{6}\frac{z-x-3}2 \frac{x-3}2\,\mathrm dx$$ then I eventually did the integral to get $(x^3/24)-((18x^2)/24)-(54x/24)-(108/24)$. unfortunately I was unable to figure this out

Comment: Do you mean $f_y(y)$ or $f_y(z)$?

Comment: Mythomorphic, it would be $f_Y(x)$.  @Bobby case sensitivity is important!  $X,Y,Z$ are random variables, $x,z$ are value tokens.

Answer (score 1):

To find the density $f_z(z)$ one approach is to first find the CDF $F_Z(z)$ and differentiate it.

Clearly, since they are independent, 
$$f_{XY}(x,y) = \frac{xy -3x-3y+9}{4}$$
on the interval $3 <x,y<5$, and is $0$ elsewhere.

Hence:

$$F_Z(z) = P(Z \leq z) = P(X + Y < z) = \int_0^z \int_0^{z-y} f_{XY}(x,y) dx dx$$

Since, if $Y=y$, then $X$ can take values up to $z-y$ and still satisfy $X+Y \leq z$. Now $f(x,y)$ is zero outside of the interval $[3,5]$ so you need to be careful where you begin the integral **AND** what value $z$ takes. If $z>10$ then clearly $P(Z<z)=1$. Similarly, it's possible the upper integrand $z-y > 5$ depending on what $z$ is, so that the inner integral needs to go up to $5$ and not $z-y$ etc.

$$F_Z(z) = \int_3^z \int_3^{z-y} f_{XY}(x,y) dxdy$$

That's the approach you need to take.

Comment: One regularly sees this détour PDF$\to$CDF$\to$CDF$\to$PDF mentioned on the site, and even recommended to compute a PDF starting from PDFs. There is a mystery here, that probably finds its source in misguided curricula choosing to focus on the CDF as the "true" description of a distribution. Not so.

Comment: To sum up: "That's the approach you need to take" is not true.

Comment: I clearly meant it as "if you take this approach, then you need to do it this way"... At the beginning of my answer i literally state "one approach is to". If someone is asking a question like this and they've never seen Jacobian transforms like the other answer uses, it definitely helps to show them another approach.

Comment: Good, so everything is clear(er) now.

Answer (score 1):

We have $f_{X,X+Y}(x,z) ~{= f_{X,Y}(x, z-x)\qquad\text{via Jacobian Transform} \\ =  f_{X}(x)f_Y(z-x) \qquad\text{by independence} \\ = \tfrac 14 (x-3)(z-x-3)\mathbf 1_{3\leqslant x\leqslant 5}\mathbf 1_{3\leqslant z-x\leqslant 5}\\ = \tfrac 14(x-3)(z-3-x)\mathbf 1_{\max(3,z-3)\leqslant x\leqslant \min(5,z-3)}\mathbf 1_{6\leqslant z\leqslant 10}}$

So the marginal pdf of the sum is $$f_{X+Y}(z) ~{= \int_\Bbb R f_X(x)f(z-x)\operatorname d x\\ = \tfrac 14\mathbf 1_{6\leqslant z\leqslant 10}\cdot\int_{\max(3,z-5)}^{\min(5,z-3)}(x-3)(z-3-x)\operatorname d x \\ = \begin{cases}\underline{\phantom{\tfrac 1{24}(z-6)^3}}&:&{6\leqslant z < 8} \\ \underline{\phantom{\tfrac 1{24}(10-z)(4-8z+z^2)}}&:& {8\leqslant z\leqslant 10}\end{cases} }$$